# React.js render components two different elements

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am in the process of transitioning an application into React. This being the case I need to be able to render components to two different elements on the dom which I am accomplishing as such:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Results />
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Search />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root-search'));
```

My issue now is trying to share the state between components which I am not sure why its not working as I am passing the Provider store to both. Updates on one and not being affected to the other.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing `Results` and `Search`.

Comment: As a side note, is there any particular reason why you're using two different provider components? Couldn't you simply wrap the `Search` components and the `Results` component into a single container?

Comment: What isn't working. Padding the Dane store to different divs _should_ work

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a legitimate reason for having more than one store, it's recommended to use only one.

You can achieve a shared state with your components by having one provider:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <Results />
      <Search />
    </div>
  </Provider> ,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Since the app is in transition its not all rendered by react. In this case I need to have the search in the header and the results after some content. Maybe I am doing something completely wrong?

Comment: "it's not all rendered by react", might be helpful to include the rest of your markup. It would help on advising if the approach your taking could be revised somehow

Comment: Rendering two different component trees, and using the same store for both of them, is a totally valid use case.  (For that matter, having two different stores is a valid approach as well, although not the normal recommended approach.)

Comment: @DavidTurton You can't share the redux state between two different stores. You must do what pineda has said if you want to share the state between these components

Comment: @markerikson: while sharing a store between two different component trees is valid, given the fact that the OP is doing so _because of the need to support existing markup non-ReactJS structure_ isn't a great reason.

Comment: I would say that's _exactly_ the use case for having one store and multiple render trees. You've got some existing non-React page, you want to start sprinkling some React in piece by piece, so you have multiple render trees.  You want to have a common set of data, so you create one store and share it.